# How to set/connect the Slider Numbers states with the slider?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

on the left and right side of my slider are the states (numbers/price) from and until how much you can search Products (Price-Slider /Price-Filter).
But the numbers are static, so If I use the slider then the numbers stay the same...
I would like the numbers to change with the slider.
How I can connect the numbers with my Slider?

Please see here (yellow marked)->SliderStates

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here the HTML Info of my filter:

```
<form action="" method="GET" class="filterform form-inline"
data-ajax="true" data-id="5657" data-source-id="95">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price7068" class="control-label">Nach Preis</label>
    <div class="slide">
        <span>1</span>
        <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
            <div class="slider-track">
                <div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 47.2047%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 52.7953%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1"
                    aria-valuemax="10000" aria-valuenow="1" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1"
                    aria-valuemax="10000" aria-valuenow="4721" tabindex="0" style="left: 47.2047%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top" role="presentation" style="left: 23.6024%; margin-left: -40px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1 € - 4721 €</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 0%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-max top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 47.2047%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">4721</div>
            </div>
        </div><input id="price7068" name="price" data-slider-label=" €" type="text" class="bt-slider" value="1,4721"
            data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10000" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="[1,10000]"
            data-value="1,4721" style="display: none;">
        <span>10000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="product_rating4028" class="control-label">Nach Bewertung</label>
    <div class="slide">
        <span>0</span>
        <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
            <div class="slider-track">
                <div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 20%; width: 80%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5"
                    aria-valuenow="1" tabindex="0" style="left: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5"
                    aria-valuenow="5" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top" role="presentation" style="left: 60%; margin-left: -58.5px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1 Sterne - 5 Sterne</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 20%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-max top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 100%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">5</div>
            </div>
        </div><input id="product_rating4028" name="product_rating" data-slider-label=" Sterne" type="text"
            class="bt-slider" value="1,5" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="0.5"
            data-slider-value="[0,5]" data-value="1,5" style="display: none;">
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="marke2417" class="control-label">Nach Marke</label>
    <select id="marke2417" name="marke[]" class="form-control" multiple="">
        <option value="msi">MSI</option>
        <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
        <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option value="sony">Sony</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="kategorie5529" class="control-label">Nach Kategorie</label>
    <select id="kategorie5529" name="kategorie" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Kategorie wählen</option>
        <option value="automotorrad">Auto &amp; Motorrad</option>
        <option value="babykinderwelt">Baby &amp; Kinderwelt</option>
        <option value="computersoftware">Computer &amp; Software</option>
        <option value="druckerscanner">&nbsp;&nbsp;Drucker &amp; Scanner</option>
        <option value="3ddruckerk">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3D-Drucker</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="layout" value=""><input type="hidden"
    name="orderby" value="">
<div class="form-group form-group-block">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-xs btn-link filter-reset pull-right">Filter zurücksetzen</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-at">
        Filtern </button>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Also my Price-Slide-PHP-Code:

```
// values & steps
        $values = at_field_database_min_max_value( $this->name, 'product' );
        if ( isset( $this->field['min_value'] ) && $this->field['min_value'] != false ) $values->min = $this->field['min_value'];
        if ( isset( $this->field['max_value'] ) && $this->field['max_value'] != false ) $values->max = $this->field['max_value'];
        $steps = at_field_step_value( $values->min, $values->max, '', $this->name );
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" class="control-label"><?php echo $title ?></label>
            <div class="slide">
                <span><?php echo $values->min; ?></span>
                <input id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>" name="<?php echo $this->name; ?>" data-slider-label="<?php echo apply_filters( 'at_filter_price_label', ' ' . at_get_default_currency( true ) ); ?>" type="text" class="bt-slider" value="<?php if ( $this->value ) {
                    echo $this->value;
                } ?>" data-slider-min="<?php echo $values->min; ?>" data-slider-max="<?php echo $values->max; ?>" data-slider-step="<?php echo $steps; ?>" data-slider-value="[<?php if ( $this->value ) {
                    echo $this->value;
                } else {
                    echo $values->min . ',' . $values->max;
                } ?>]">
                <span><?php echo $values->max; ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php echo( $instruction ? '<span class="filter-instruction">' . $instruction . '</span>' : '' ); ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the script i provided you before by this:

```
    let filterForm = document.querySelector("form.filterform");
if (null !== filterForm) {
    let waitS = setInterval(wait_sliders, 200);
    function wait_sliders() {
        if (null !== filterForm.querySelector(".slider-handle")) {

            // Listen new values
            let slides = filterForm.querySelectorAll('.slide');
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                    if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
                        let values = mutation.target.value.split(',');
                        let spans = mutation.target.closest('.slide').querySelectorAll('span');
                        spans[0].innerText = values[0];
                        spans[spans.length - 1].innerText = values[1];
                    }
                });
            });
            
            slides.forEach(slide => {
                let el = slide.querySelector('.bt-slider');
                observer.observe(el, { attributes: true });
            });
            
            filterForm.querySelectorAll("input,select,.slider-handle").forEach((e) => {
                let event = e.classList.contains("slider-handle") ? ["mouseup", "touchend"] : ["change"];
                for (let i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
                    e.addEventListener(event[i], (e) => {
                        filterForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();
                    });
                }
            }),
                filterForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();
            clearInterval(waitS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know how, but all comments was deleted.....
I have one point:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830458/yith-woocommerce-wishlist-without-woocommerce
Can you help here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611593/how-to-collapse-my-sidebarfilter-each-filter-value Can you help me out here with this issue :) please?

Comment: Hello I have created the following filter:
https://entdeckepreise.de/kategorie/minipcs/

Now I have above the products (desktop view) another filter possibility (sorting or also to change the view how the products should be displayed) -> Grid or List view.

This does not work with the JavaScript code is there the possibility to implement this sorting in the code as well?
I hope you can help me, thank you in advanced!

To know what I mean, if you go to the URL you find "Ansicht" above the products (Change the View) and "Neuheiten" thats the sorting the products (Price,Name, etc)

Comment: Please help me, it's enough if you can solve my sorting issue only .. please

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for a solution without a separate javascript code. There is little easy solution without writing a javascript or jquery function:

```html
1<input type="range" value="100" min="1" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value">

<output>100</output>
```

Made a new solution with js only

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
            values: [1, 100],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                if ( ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1] ) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                            document.getElementById("spanMin").textContent= ui.values[1];    
                            document.getElementById("spanMax").textContent= ui.values[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    
        $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.slidersStyle div, span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="slidersStyle">
      <span id="spanMax" style="display: inline-block;" class="sliderValue">1</span>
      <div style="width:300px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;" id="slider">           </div>    
      <span id="spanMin" class="sliderValue">100</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#slider").slider({
                min: 1,
                max: 10000,
                step: 1,
                values: [1, 10000],
                slide: function(event, ui) {
                    if ( ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1] ) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                                document.getElementById("spanMin").textContent= ui.values[1];    
                                document.getElementById("spanMax").textContent= ui.values[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        
            $("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
            });
        });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">  
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="https://entdeckepreise.de/filter/produktfilter/" method="GET" class="filterform form-inline"
data-ajax="true" data-id="5657" data-source-id="95">
<div class="form-group" style="margin: 50px;">
    <label for="price7068" class="control-label">Nach Preis</label>
    <div class="slide">
        <span id="spanMax" style="display: inline-block;" class="sliderValue">1</span>
        <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
            <div class="slider-track">
                <div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 47.2047%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 52.7953%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1"
                    aria-valuemax="10000" aria-valuenow="1" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1"
                    aria-valuemax="10000" aria-valuenow="4721" tabindex="0" style="left: 47.2047%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top" role="presentation" style="left: 23.6024%; margin-left: -40px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1 € - 4721 €</div>
                <div style="width:300px; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;" id="slider">           </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 0%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-max top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 47.2047%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">4721</div>
            </div>
        </div><input id="price7068" name="price" data-slider-label=" €" type="text" class="bt-slider" value="1,4721"
            data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="10000" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="[1,10000]"
            data-value="1,4721" style="display: none;">
        <span id="spanMin" class="sliderValue">10000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="product_rating4028" class="control-label">Nach Bewertung</label>
    <div class="slide">
        <span>0</span>
        <div class="slider slider-horizontal" id="">
            <div class="slider-track">
                <div class="slider-track-low" style="left: 0px; width: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-selection" style="left: 20%; width: 80%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-track-high" style="right: 0px; width: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5"
                    aria-valuenow="1" tabindex="0" style="left: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5"
                    aria-valuenow="5" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-main top" role="presentation" style="left: 60%; margin-left: -58.5px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1 Sterne - 5 Sterne</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-min top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 20%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip tooltip-max top" role="presentation"
                style="left: 100%; margin-left: 0px; display: none;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
                <div class="tooltip-inner">5</div>
            </div>
        </div><input id="product_rating4028" name="product_rating" data-slider-label=" Sterne" type="text"
            class="bt-slider" value="1,5" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="0.5"
            data-slider-value="[0,5]" data-value="1,5" style="display: none;">
        <span>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="marke2417" class="control-label">Nach Marke</label>
    <select id="marke2417" name="marke[]" class="form-control" multiple="">
        <option value="msi">MSI</option>
        <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
        <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
        <option value="sony">Sony</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="kategorie5529" class="control-label">Nach Kategorie</label>
    <select id="kategorie5529" name="kategorie" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Kategorie wählen</option>
        <option value="automotorrad">Auto &amp; Motorrad</option>
        <option value="babykinderwelt">Baby &amp; Kinderwelt</option>
        <option value="computersoftware">Computer &amp; Software</option>
        <option value="druckerscanner">&nbsp;&nbsp;Drucker &amp; Scanner</option>
        <option value="3ddruckerk">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3D-Drucker</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="layout" value=""><input type="hidden"
    name="orderby" value="">
<div class="form-group form-group-block">
    <a href="/" class="btn btn-xs btn-link filter-reset pull-right">Filter zurücksetzen</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-at">
        Filtern </button>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Your design is now also implemented here**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
     range: true,
     min: 1,
     max: 100,
     values: [ 1, 100 ],
     slide: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#min" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
       $( "#max" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
     }
   });
 });
```

```css
body {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
}

#min   {
   width:14px;
}


.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
   border-radius: 50%!important;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
   width: 1.8em!important;
   height: 1.8em!important;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
   top: -0.45em!important;
}

.ui-widget-content {
   background: #dddddd!important;
}

.ui-widget-header {
   background: #9ac836!important;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="min" value="1" readonly style="border:0; display:inline-block;">
   <div id="slider-range" style="width:200px; margin:0px 25px; display: inline-block;" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
   <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" style=""></div>
      <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></span>
      <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default"></span>
   </div>
  <input type="text" id="max" value="100" readonly style="border:0; display:inline-block;">
</form>
```

Comment: No,  it's almost the same thing i have....
If you use the Slider, the 1 or the 100 (your example) should change the value.
No extra field should be generated

Comment: Your Code is good to Do so:
1<input type="range" value="24" min="1" max="100" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value"><output>100</output>$

Comment: Can you also build a example with two dots?
One starts at the 1 position and the other one at the 100 position?

Comment: @Leonwalker Yes I've just made one, it's a bit more complex than the other example I did, hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for that.. but how I can implement this function in my php?
I have added my PHP Code

Comment: @Leonwalker Is it possible to post a picture of how your page looks atm? and where this should be implemented, then I can do it :)

Comment: @Leonwalker Please approve the answer if its usable

Comment: Hi Mads,
https://entdeckepreise.de
There you can see the Sliders at the homepage
"Nach Preis" & "Nach Bewertung"

Comment: Hi Mads, sorry but your code is a other only :)
It's not solve my Matter :)
If you can implement it to my code then I can set it as solved.

Comment: It's a bit hard to do it with the code you provided, but tried to change my code, so I use js. Now I change the span values you have by `ID` `document.getElementById("spanMin").textContent= ui.values[1]; ` and these can also be changed to `inputs` if you want them to be submitted or somthing like that or make some hidden inputs with these values. But It should be fairly easy to implement this now, just remember to import the `libaries` that i did in the html part @Leonwalker

Comment: Okay it's looks good... but how I can implement it now to my php code?
I also see you have create a extra Price-Filter.
The PHP-Function (my site) allows to create Filters (majority), thats the reason with ID
I think if I implement it to my Site it should create a same filter for alle Filters..
Please help me out here.

I use Wordpress and I am very new here, where and how to implement it

Comment: PS: its a bootsrap slider

Comment: @Leonwalker can you add id's to the spans you have? then add for min value this id `id="spanMin"` and for max i`id="spanMax"`, then just use the javascript code, and give the slider the id `id="slider"` the js code can just be but into a `?> <script> ... </script> <?php`

Comment: Remember my solution is for doing it all yourself, no drag and drop :)

Comment: Okay so i have 
<span id="spanMin"><?php echo $values->min; ?></span> and
<span id="spanMax"><?php echo $values->max; ?></span>

Then I have added the JS Code to the footer at my page with <script></script>

But I can't find the php-File for slider

Comment: Sorry Mads, I am simply too inexperienced here

Comment: It's okay @Leonwalker just to finish it a bit I've made the code look like the one you want :) But looks like the other solution might be working for you?

Comment: thank you for your time! It looks good.
But for me works the other one very well and it easier for me to implement it.
If I had the opportunity i would mark it also as solution.

Comment: @Leonwalker If it's possible a thumps up on my answer would be appreciated :D glad you found a solution

Comment: Sorry Mads, I need further 15 reputations to cast a vote